# Debuguear desde un proyecto windows form a un proyecto aplicacion web (en la misma solucion)

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, aplicación-web, aplicación-escritorio

Hola tengo una solucion en vb 2005, en dicha solucion tengo proyectos(windows forms y aplicacion web). Y lo que quiero es debuguear desde un proyecto windows forms que llegue a un proyecto aplicacion web. Hasta el momento no puedo acceder.

Agradeceria sus respuestas.

Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: mmm... no comprendo bien tu pregunta. ¿estás haciendo un debugger? el debugger debe tener el mismo nivel de privilegio que la aplicación target, si intentas depurar un servicio, tu debugger debe correr en una sesión privilegiada. ¿cuál es el problema que tienes?

Comment: Hola ,, no estoy haciendo un debugger,, en la solucion,, hay proyectos que son aplicaciones de escritorio y otros que son aplicaciones web,, Y lo que quiero hacer (en tiempo de ejecucion) es  desde una aplicación de escritorio acceder al codigo de una aplicacion web. Agradeceria tu ayuda.

Comment: ¿para qué querrías hacer algo así en un proyecto que no es un debugger?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la soluccion levanta la aplicacion de escritorio,, y hay una referencia a la aplicacion web,, me esta saliendo un error, y es en la aplicación web, y me gustaria seguir el codigo. Gracias.

Comment: lo mas simple seria montar tu web en iis y al ejecutar tu winform crear una instancia WebClient que apunte a tu sitio en el iss(usualmente localhost) de todas formas, pa quequieres hacer esto?

Comment: Lo mas sencillo es pasar el sitio al `IIS`, cuando levantas el `Windows Form`, en el menu `Debug` hay un submenu `attach Process`, debes marcar el `check` de mostrar los procesos de todos los usuarios, en estos debe estar los procesos   **aspnet_wp.exe** (IIS<=5) o w3wp.exe,  para esto es nesesario derechos de administrador y que el site web este ejecuntandose, por lo que procura correr una vez la aplicacion `Windoms Form` o llamar el `Web Site`  desde el `Browser`